# Deducting a percentage with smarty math

Tags: php, smarty

Not sure on how to do this within Smarty, but this is what i'm trying to do.

Deduct 25.5% from the price.

```
{math assign="$percentage" equation="(x - y)" x=$product.price y="25.5%" format="%.2f"}
{$percentage}
```

But i've found out that doing the

```
y="25.5%"
```

does not work, i've tried researching on the best practice, but so far nothing that i found that i understood...

Any ideas very welcome ;)

Comment: `x - (y/100*x)`.... and `y` should be a number (`25.5`) without the percentage sign

Answer (score 1):

First thing - if possible you should do such calculation in PHP and simple assign result to Smarty. In most cases it's the best way. You need to also notice:

> {math} is an expensive function in performance due to its use of the
>   php eval() function. Doing the math in PHP is much more efficient, so
>   whenever possible do the math calculations in the script and assign()
>   the results to the template. Definitely avoid repetitive {math}
>   function calls, eg within {section} loops.

But let's assume you still want to do it directly in Smarty

First thing, when you use assign in math you shouldn't use `$` before variable name so it should be `{math assign="percentage"` and not `{math assign="$percentage"`

You cannot use percentage in y so you need to do it this way:

```
{math assign="percentage" equation="(100-y)/100 * x" x=$product.price y="25.5" format="%.2f"}
{$percentage}
```

or this way

```
{math assign="percentage" equation="(1-y/100) * x" x=$product.price y="25.5" format="%.2f"}
{$percentage}
```

or you simple should pass not 25.5 as y but already divide it by 100 so 0.255 as below

```
{math assign="percentage" equation="(1-y) * x" x=$product.price y="0.255" format="%.2f"}
{$percentage}
```

All those method generate the same, expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `math` or `assign`, just do the calculation directly, though as Mark Baker said, `$y` needs to be a number (0.255), not a percentage string:

```
{($product.price - ($product.price * $y))|string_format:"%.2f%%"}
```

You could put the percentage character outside the Smarty tag, but I've put it in the `string_format` so it's self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all familiar with Smarty, but you need to multiply the price by the percentage (expressed as a decimal value from 0 to 1) to get the discount, then subtract that value from the original price. So, the equation you're looking for is:

```
x - (.255 * x)
```

Which may or may not work within Smarty:

```
{math assign="$percentage" equation="(x - (.255 * x))" x=$product.price format="%.2f"}
```